# Read and Write files from internal storage within a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an app that has a `SplashScreen` and a `MainActivity`. In the `MainActivity` a `FrameLayout` gets replaced by fragments. But this is just a basic understanding and I don't think it's really needed for my problem.

In my SplashScreen I'm checking if a file exists on the internal storage. If it does it gets read out. If it doesn't, it gets downloaded from the internet. So far so good. Now, when the user is in the MainActivity he has different options. Dependent on that option a Fragment will be opened and displays data. This data is different. So now I wanted to do the same like in the SplashScreen there. Check if the file exists. If it does, read it out, otherwise download from Internet. The problem I'm encountering is, that it seems that reading and writing is not possible via Fragments. Is that correct?

The fragment stars an AsyncTask and should do the downloading in there.

This is the code I have in the Fragment for writing to a file

```
private void writeToFile(String data, String filename) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput( filename, MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

But the problem I have is at `MODE_PRIVATE` - The error I have is `MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable` . How can I set the mode to private in the fragment?

Then, when I want to read a file it works in the SplashScreen like that

`inputStream = openFileInput ( filepath )`

But in the fragment I get the error

`The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type WeekFragment.MainAsyncTask`

How exactly do I write and read from files within a fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) is constant of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class. So you can access it from anywhere using  `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

So in your code use like

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(getActivity().openFileOutput( filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

Comment: Hey, when I do this I get an error at the method `openFileOutput` with the error

`The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type WeekFragment`

Comment: For that use `getActivity().openFileOutput`

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted you. When I modified my code and it works I will accept your answer.

Comment: Your most welcome.. congs you resolved your issue :)

Comment: Hey, it's me again. So far everything works except for one thing. When I try to write the file it tells me that there is a NullPointerException in this line

`OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(c.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("mainXML.xml", c.MODE_PRIVATE));`

What could be the problem? I do `Context c = new MainActivity()` in the onCreate of the fragment

Comment: Don't do that. Use instead `Context c = getActivity();`. You can not do new MainActivity() for an Activity. And one more thing, you are using `c.MODE_PRIVATE`, because Constants are class variables so you should use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

Comment: So it would be `c.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput ( filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE` , right?

That's working! Thanks. Take my upvotes

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in fragment

```
//reading text from the file
FileInputStream fileIn = getActivity().openFileInput("FragmentFile.txt");
```

and

```
//write text to file
try {
FileOutputStream fileout = getActivity().openFileOutput("FragmentFile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
                        outputWriter.write(response.toString());
                        outputWriter.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
}}
```